# No content to map due to end-of-input swagger maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, swagger

I am including security definitions in `pom.xml` file. When I run a goal `mvn compile`, it throws an exception:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.kongchen:swagger-maven-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default) on project test: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input

I have included security definitions in Swagger Maven plugin as below

```
<securityDefinitions>
  <securityDefinition>
     <json>src/main/resources/securityDefinition.json</json>
  </securityDefinition>
</securityDefinitions>
```

I have tried with `${basedir}` but still get the above exception. How can this be resolved also as the spec says?

The file will be read by `getClass().getResourceAsStream`, so please note the path you configured. How can I fullfil this condition?

Comment: I've made some suggestions in an answer. Can you supply a link to the swagger plugin you are using please in your question. mt Rob.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait to next plugin release (3.1.6). They just merged the changes to the master branch with the solution to the classpath file loading problem that you are facing. The classloader used when the plugin executes has no access to the project's files, be it resources or Java source files.

Next release will have a `<jsonPath>` tag to allow access to file location and `<json>` tag for classpath file loading (solving the problem).

---

**Update** (tested):

If you don't mind about it you can use the 3.1.6-SNAPSHOT version.

Then, in your POM:

```
<securityDefinitions>
    <securityDefinition>                            
      <jsonPath>${project.basedir}/securityDefinition.json</jsonPath>
    </securityDefinition>                                                                   
</securityDefinitions>
```

And in the JSON file follow the author's intructions:

https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin

Comment: Do you know what the release number will be that contains a solution to this problem?

Comment: next version, 3.1.6